# Can my server subscribe to all writes to a program's accounts?

Tags: rpc, webhook, subscription, database, index

I want to query a data-based index of accounts. For example, if my dapp stores posts and user profiles on chain, I might want to query all posts by a cetain user.

I could index all posts by user on-chain, but this will have all sorts of costs. The canonical solution seems like it would be running a web2 database that copies all of my program's accounts in realtime and lets me write arbitrary indices.

In order to do this, my server would ideally be able to subscribe to all writes to my program's accounts so that it could write to the database ASAP.

However, I'm simply not aware of any RPC call, IaaS product, etc. that would make this possible. The only solution I can think of would be writing a custom validator plugin. Am I missing something? Can I in fact subscribe to writes / events from my program using a normal RPC node?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question but I'm guessing what would be more useful to you is the [getProgramAccounts RPC method](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getprogramaccounts). You can pass a memcmp parameter that lets you filter results as part of the RPC.

Comment: Note that you need to be using an RPC endpoint that actually supports this (like QuickNode). gPA has been removed from native Solana endpoints.

Comment: I wasn't aware of how memcap worked -- that would indeed be useful, since in my example I could just store `author` as the first part of the post account data. However, I am unsure if RPC nodes are able to performantly perform these filters. 

You can imagine a world where I could tell my validator or RPC provider "hey, please maintain an index of accounts that meet this filter criteria, so I can query it quickly". That seems like it would probably be perfectly sufficient in most cases. However, I'm not sure this ability exists.

Comment: @verata-veritatis Really? I have an application on main-net that utilizes gPA. When was this removal implemented?

I am not sure that QuickNode does support gPA, as it is not listed in their list of API calls: https://www.quicknode.com/docs/solana/getAccountInfo

Comment: I'd move this to its own question.

Comment: @AgrippaKellum Yes, I remember Solana announcing they accidentally forced nodes to upgrade from 1.8 to 1.9, which borked gPA. https://twitter.com/GenesysGo/status/1508295993581871104 . I wasn't able to use gPA at all for months (maybe they fixed this recently?) Response typically returned empty or "The RPC call or parameters have been disabled."

Comment: Just to add, getProgramAccounts is a pretty heavy method, but most providers support it https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/solana-getting-started

Answer (score 1):

RPC isn't suited for something like this at scale.  You'd want to build a [Geyser Plugin](https://docs.solana.com/developing/plugins/geyser-plugins) that streams account updates, filters and builds a database optimized for your application